# how to rotate google map for iphone app

Tags: iphone, xcode, google-maps, mkmapview

I am doing map oriented iphone application.In that am showing an area on google map.That area is placed in horizantal view.I want to rotate it in vertical view.Any idea?Please help me.I attached the map image below.

[image]

Comment: what do you mean by vertical view..you want to change orientation of map when your device is vertical or something else??

Comment: no.am not asking about orientation.I am using default google map.The area shown in above google map is shown in east-west side.I want to show it in north-south side.

Comment: ok so you want to rotate the whole map..

Comment: If the map is static, as in won't zoom or pan as the user moves you might want to consider fetching it via the Google Maps Static API (if that is allowable on iOS). That way you'd just have a jpeg to rotate, pretty easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To rotate the view, I would suggest to use the `CGAffineTransform` to rotate the view.
As your map is shown in the mapView, you can rotate it.

```
float   angle = M_PI;  //rotate 180°, or 1 π radians
CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(angle);
[[self viewWithTag:999] setTransform:transform]; //you can use the view or its tag
```

hope that helps